# Fastest Way to build this ifelse loop in R

Tags: r, performance, loops

What i am trying to do is :

1. Generate a Randon Number between 0 and 1

   ```
   rand_number <- runif(1,0,1)
   ```
2. Depending on the randon number generated i atribute the value 1,2,3,4 or 5 to the variable **bet_choice**

   ```
   bet_choice <- ifelse(rand_number<0.1,1,
                    ifelse(rand_number>0.1 & rand_number<=0.4,2,
                           ifelse(rand_number>0.4 & rand_number<=0.7,3,
                                  ifelse(rand_number>0.7 & rand_number<=0.9,4,5))))
   ```

I am repeating this simulation 1000 times and i feel that using ifelse is not the optimal way to reah this goal. Is there a way to avoid the ifelse loop and improve performance of this part of the code ?

I have the complete code on what i am trying to do in (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12868/kelly-capital-growth-investment-strategy-example-in-r) in case someone is interested in the complete code.

Comment: I think `cut` may be your friend here.

Comment: ...which of course assumes that you switch to creating all the random numbers up front with `runif(1000,0,1)`, rather than one at a time, which of course will be terribly slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upvoted josilber's answers because I think it is very good. But I'd just add that you're really sampling from a particular discrete distribution where you use the uniform random variable to select the random number with the correct probabilities. You can use `sample` to get the same results with the following:

```
s <- sample(1:5, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1))
```

You can test it yourself, but I believe this should be even faster.

**edit** I've now tested it with the following:

```
library(microbenchmark)
s1 <- function() sample(1:5, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1,.3,.3,.2,.1))
s2 <- function() sample.int(5, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1,.3,.3,.2,.1))
microbenchmark(s1(), s2())
#Unit: microseconds
# expr    min     lq median     uq    max neval
# s1() 39.389 40.536 41.300 41.683 76.483   100
# s2() 29.828 30.594 31.358 31.741 43.213   100
```

It seems that `sample.int` is even faster and yield a 16.9x speed up from josilber's `version2`.

Comment: How would i go on creating a matrix which the columns are the number of simulations and each simulation generates 700 random numbers ?
I tried 
`simu_matrix <- matrix(sample.int(5, size = 700, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1,.3,.3,.2,.1)),nrow=700,ncol=1000)`
But this generates the same 700 random numbers for every column.